# Calculating SHA 3 Hash in Java

Tags: java, sha-3

I have been using CryptoJS (i.e. `CryptoJS.algo.SHA3.creat()`) library to SHA-3 hash on the front end. (see http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha3.js)

I was wondering if there are any Java library equivalence? But so far I haven't found any. There are not so many Java SHA-3 examples either.

`sun.security.Provider` has SHA-3, but it's not visible under Eclipse. Also, I am not sure whether this sun's SHA-3 is same as the CryptoJS's SHA-3.

Could anyone please provide some examples?

Comment: FWIW, you can, in fact, access sun.* classes in Eclipse. For the project where you need to reference the classes, define project-specific Java Build Path -> Libraries and make sure the reference to the "JRE System Library" is both a standalone, Installed JRE (not the JRE in an install JDK) and is referenced as an "Alternate JRE". [Not that I'd recommend doing this...]

Comment: @jdv The `sun.*` classes are hidden for a reason. You should not use them, or you risk your program being broken on a future Java version. See [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs 
That Call 'sun' Packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Comment: @Jesper, I am aware of this, which is why my comments and answer have obvious caveats around them.

Comment: [JEP 287: SHA-3 Hash Algorithms](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/287)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The common Java reference implementation for crypto and crypto support is probably [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/). It can be a big library to bring in, which is why we often reach into sun.security (rightly or wrongly.)

Anyway, [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) seems to offer `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA3.DigestSHA3`

Answer (score 27):

Thanks to @jdv for his answer.
I'm adding more information to have a quick start and an example.

First, add the BouncyCastle maven dependency, or get it on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.bouncycastle%22%20AND%20a%3A%22bcpkix-jdk15on%22) :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.56</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then we can test it :

```
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA3;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
import org.junit.Test;

@Test
public void testSha3() throws Exception {
    String input = "Hello world !";
    SHA3.DigestSHA3 digestSHA3 = new SHA3.Digest512();
    byte[] digest = digestSHA3.digest(input.getBytes());

    System.out.println("SHA3-512 = " + Hex.toHexString(digest));
}
```

You'll get this result (512 bits or 64 bytes in hexadecimal) :

> SHA3-512 = e9a4fd120d684537d57f314d51213ce5acef8ff6974e2b7599674ef0f0a3cf111f0d26ed602db946739da448210fb76a7621d7a8f07728372b10a975f36d8e37

You can compare it with this result : https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sha3+%22Hello+world+!%22&ia=answer

Comment: Thanks for answer and howto: I implemented it on java8 without problems. Though in my project on java11 I get an `error: cannot find symbol` on this line: `byte[] digest = digestSHA3.digest(message.getBytes());`. Anybody some experience with bouncy castle and java11? In the mvn repo it writes java5 - java8...

Comment: Java 11 has digest methods https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml.crypto/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/DigestMethod.html

Answer (score 1):

A new answer to an old question, in case others are searching like I was.

In Java 11 and later, there are 4 SHA-3 hashes available from the standard "Sun" security provider. Just ask for them by name with no other special configuration or code:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA3-256");
```

The other three available are `SHA3-224`, `SHA3-384` and `SHA3-512`.

Official documentation of the [supported `MessageDigest` algorithm names](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#messagedigest-algorithms) is available.